# Java XSSFSheet cannot get the correct date value

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Java `XSSFSheet` cannot get the correct date value.

It displays an invalid number.
I gave in excel as date: 9/24/2017

But while debugging the date displays as 43002
[image]

Please tell me the solution.

Comment: Have you got chance to try the given solution?

Answer (score 1):

It evident from the screen shot that the date used in the excel and the date format to parse the same is not matching.

In order to solve the issue, make the following changes

- Use the date in excel as `09/24/2017`
- In the class, change the date format as `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: It's not working for me.It automatically changed to m/d/yy format

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you elaborate it ? add screen shot if required?

Comment: Are you setting the data in excel manually? or by any program?

Comment: view my image : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sysramthiru/test/master/bug.JPG

Comment: What is the ouput shown while reading the same? can you show your code how you are reading it? Can you check if this helps - http://www.kianworknotes.com/2013/07/reading-and-writing-date-value-in-excel.html

Comment: CELL_TYPE is STRING

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add respective code? which is currently being hidden by the screen shot.

Comment: Thanks, @Rao I fixed now. i accdiently added  this code `cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);` . now i removed and fixed.

Comment: Because of you I got the solution from above link http://www.kianworknotes.com/2013/07/reading-and-writing-date-value-in-excel.html  The cell value need to be numeric but I overwrite it as a string so the problem comes. now I fixed.